# UITableView items not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which reads items from an `NSMutableArray` called **friendsList**.

I initialise this array here:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.title = TA(@"Find Friends", @"");
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self createRightNavBarButton];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self createLeftNavBarButton];
        friendsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have set it's `datasource` method for `numberOfRows` to return `friendslist.count` if the count is **greater than zero**.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (friendsList.count) {
        return friendsList.count;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

After I fill the array in another method I'm calling `[tableView reloadData]` so that the `datasource` method is called again to read the count of the objects in the array.

```
- (void)loadContactsFromSource:(ListSource)source
{
    if (friendsList) {
        [friendsList removeAllObjects];
    }
    switch (source) {
        case LS_Facebook:
            break;
        case LS_Twitter:            
            break;
        case LS_Contacts:{
            ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                if (granted) {
                    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
                    CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(
                                                                               kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                               CFArrayGetCount(allPeople),
                                                                               allPeople
                                                                               );
                    CFArraySortValues(
                                      peopleMutable,
                                      CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)),
                                      (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName,
                                      (void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering()
                                      );

                    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

                    for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
                    {
                        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(peopleMutable, i);
                        [self copyContactToArray:ref];
                    }
                    [tableFriends reloadData];
                }
                else{
                    [PopupHandler popupDialogWithTitle:T(@"Error", @"")
                                               message:T(@"Access denied", @"")
                                              delegate:nil];
                }
            });
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the cellForRow method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *currentPerson = [friendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = [self fillCell:cell withUserInfo:currentPerson];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that after this table remains blank, the items from the array are not show. If I touch the table with my finger the items show up instantly, as if the touch somehow refreshes the table. Any ideas what might be causing this?

I'm testing this on an iPhone 5 with iOS 7, built from XCode 5.0.1 .

Comment: Can you show us the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Of course, I will add it now

Comment: where are you calling loadContactsFromSource this method..

Comment: Paste also your `fillCell:withUserInfo:` method, because something doesn't seem right there

Comment: It looks like `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(` is being called on a separate thread and the block that it runs when completed is not in the main thread.  So updating the UI inside the block will not work properly.  Try either creating a function and calling that function on the main thread from inside your addressbook return or doing a `dispatch_async` inside the addressbook return block.  If it is running in the main thread, then you can ignore this comment as it will not be the issue.

Comment: @C_X i have a segmented control, and when the value changes i call this method.

Comment: @Putz1103 How do I check if it's running in the main thread?

Comment: @Levi That is a very trivial method, it just sets the cell's properties to values from the dictionary, nothing special.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the return block from the addressbook call (probably on `reloaddata` would be good).  Then check the call stack in xcode.  If it's broken inside thread 1 then you are in the main thread, if it's in thread 2 or greater then it's a background thread.

Comment: @Putz1103 It says Thread 3.

Comment: ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion never get call on main thread by default... 
you have load tableView from main thread...

Comment: Then use this code: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tableFriends reloadData];;
    });`

Comment: Verify that by the time `reloadData` is called (once you get it called on the main thread), that the array actually has some objects in it.

Comment: Does it modify just the cell you are passing to it and returning the same object or does it create a new cell and returns that instance, because the latter could be bad. Usually these methods shouldn't return anything, you just pass them the cell, and they do their thing. That was the suspicious part for me, that you are reassigning your `cell` variable.

Comment: Thank you, I will fix that part. Otherwise, the problem was solved by Putz1103's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is being called on a separate thread and the block that it runs when completed is not in the main thread. So updating the UI inside the block will not work properly. Try either creating a function and calling that function on the main thread from inside your addressbook return or doing a dispatch_async inside the addressbook return block.

Inside your return block from `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` dispatch into the main thread by either using `dispatch_async` or `performSelectorOnMainThread`.